# How do I host my MERN app in vercel in the correct way?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, deployment, mern, vercel

I want to host it in vercel but only the client was working and the server did not start. so all the post and get requests failed.
I think I messed up in the vercel.json file. can anyone help me with this

my directory looks like this

> Notesapp

- backend

  - models
  - routes

  - package.json
  - package-lock.json
  - server.js
- client

  - build  <-- I have deleted this one
  - public

  - src

    - pages
    - components

    - app js and other standard react files

  - package.json
  - package-lock.json
- vercel.json

my vercel.json file:

```
{
    "rewrites":[
      {
        "source": "/api/(.*)",
        "destination" : "/Backend/server.js"
      }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you share your `server.js` file?

Comment: here is the link of the ripo https://github.com/KoushikSarkarGit/MERN-Notesapp
i tried some other code. it did not work

Comment: getting this after deployment
                                                       
{
"errno": -2,
"code": "ENOENT",
"syscall": "stat",
"path": "/var/task/Backend/build/index.html",
"expose": false,
"statusCode": 404,
"status": 404
}